# Transactional call to Spring from legacy code

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

We have a legacy JEE-application with a modernized spring core. Sometimes, calls are made from the JEE part into Spring. When deployed on the JEE-Server, a configured JTA-Transactionmanager handles the transactional issues sufficiently.

In integration tests outside a real JEE-Container this is not the case. When we start a transaction outside the Spring core and call a `@Transactional` method from within the core, the transaction gets used all-right but after terminating the `@Transactional` method, Spring commits the transaction (a behaviour not seen when using JTA).

Is there any way to configure Spring such that `@Transactional` checks for a running transaction and only terminates transactions it opend itself?

Comment: maybe you need smth like `@Transactional(propogation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NOT_SUPPORTED

Comment: Hi, I don't think, this solves my issue. Basically the root issue is Spring not detecting the outside transaction, and assuming it did open its own transaction (it did not, it just used the outside TX)